# PostreSQL Using named exec with custom parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

need help for advice. I'm using library `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` and wanted to use func `NamedExecContext` but I need another parameter to be like `$` like below:

```
type DummyStruct struct {
  ID int64 `json:"id" db:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name" db:"name"`
  City string `json:"city" db:"city"`
}

func main(){
  param := DummyStruct{
    Name: "a",
    City: "b",
  }
  _, err := db.NamedExec(fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE tableDummy SET name = :name, city = :city WHERE id in (%s)`, "1,2,3"), param)
}
```

So like above example, I need to implement bind struct and also placeholder args `$` because using `%s` would cause chance of SQL injection.

so I try to use it like this `UPDATE tableDummy SET name = :name, city = :city WHERE id in ($1)` -> is this posbile?

Comment: You *should* be able to start with $3 here, but nothing stops you from naming the placeholders :x1, :x2, and so forth. What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Because NamedExec only expect 1 parameter (which is interface{}), I cant set another param after the `param`. Usually after the query, you just append another args because the param is `...interface{}`.

Comment: Right, I mis-remembered the API. You cannot use named parameters for this query.